# Is it possible to set a page layout when creating a site OOTB (using UI)?

Tags: 2010, page-layout, publishing-site, sitepages

I have created a custom page layout for a publishing site (SharePoint 2010). When i create a subsite using SharePoint UI, the default.aspx page is created with a another page layout. **Is it possible to set my page layout as the default one for each new site creation ?**

Answer (score 1):

The changes can be made in site definition files. If the site created by you is using custom site template(You have created template) you can set it in the onet.xml file of the Site definition.

In the onet.xml, refer the module in the configuration and define the module int he following way

```
<Modules>
    <Module Name="Default" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
        <File Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
            <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/tabviewpagelayout.aspx, $Resources:spscore,TabViewPageLayoutTitle;" />
            <Property Name="Title" Value="$Resources:spscore,SiteDirectoryPageTitle;" />
```

........

If the site collection is not created by created by you, the onet.xml will be of sharepoint provided template onet.xml and any changes made to this file will impact the server farm.